# psycopg2, SELECT, and schemas

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying to do a simple select statement on a table that's part of the "dam_vector" schema. The error I get is:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation
>   "dam_vector.parcels_full" does not
>   exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM
>   "dam_vector.parcels_full"

I can't figure this out and know I'm missing something obvious. Any help you can provide would be great.

Here's the code I'm using. db is a connection string that successfully connects to the database.

```
cur = db.cursor()
query = 'SELECT * FROM "dam_vector.parcels_full"'
cur.execute(query)
results = cur.fetchall()
```

and when that failed and after I did some research on Google I tried this. Same error.

```
cur.execute("SET search_path TO dam_vector,public")
db.commit()

cur = db.cursor()
query = 'SELECT * FROM "parcels_full"'
cur.execute(query)
results = cur.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 5):

Double quotes makes whatever is in them an identifier, so query

```
SELECT * FROM "dam_vector.parcels_full";
```

hits table `dam_vector.parcels_full` (period interpreted as part of table name) from schama `public` (or anything in search path).

As Adam said, you don't need quotes with names without some special characters.
Try:

```
SELECT * FROM dam_vector.parcels_full;
```

If you really want to use a double quotes, go for:

```
SELECT * FROM "dam_vector"."parcels_full";
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the quotes around `dam_vector.parcels_full`.

Does the output of the following show that a `parcels_full` table is indeed present?

```
cur.execute("""SELECT tablename 
                 FROM pg_tables 
                WHERE tablename NOT LIKE ALL (ARRAY['pg_%','sql_%']);""")
cur.fetchall()
```